# Command 'wireshark' not found, what should I do?

Tags: 20.04

please I am new to Ubuntu and I have installed `wireshark` as one of the packages I need in my Core-Network emulator. However, when I also used  `apt list --installed` command to display all the installed packages, I was able to confirm that wireshark is one of the packages but surprisingly, when I tried to call it by using `wireshark` in the terminal, the error message I get is **Command 'wireshark' not found, but can be installed with:**
**sudo apt install wireshark-qt**
Having already installed wireshark, please what should I do?

Comment: Did you install it correctly? Please try `sudo apt install wireshark-qt` and report back.

Comment: @Raffles - thanks for your suggestion, I have installed it using that command.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install it with Synaptic Package Manager. I just installed it and it works just fine. What I noticed is that when I installed it with Synaptic (which requires superuser privileges) it asked me if I would allow non-superusers to have access to it, which I denied. So only a superuser can run it.